# sql query to select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have only one tables and that table has 3 values for one records.
Example:

**Record 1**

1. Values as per id
2. Values as per dates
3. Values as a default

I have to write query in such a way that it select values in following way.

```
if
  values present for id then select values by id
if not
then 
   if values present for dates then select by dates 
if not
   Then if values for default taken
```

How should i write single SQL query to select values?

Please keep in mind that there is always default values but there may be may not be values for id and dates.

Comment: i have create one temp table and insert by id then check if values not there then again insert by dates and see again if values not there then insert defaults but not good solution i want in one query

Comment: This is a bit unclear, when you say "values present", do you mean per row, or for whole table? (I.e. check for every single row which value to return, or first check and then select that column for the whole table?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement

Something like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN id
            WHEN dates IS NOT NULL THEN dates
            ELSE [default]
        END
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table 2 ON table1.id = table2.id
.
.
.
```

and so on

Comment: my 3 tables are actually created from joins of multiple tables so you need to consider each table as separate new table

Comment: Ok then put joins in your SELECT statement.